# yum reinstall installs two kernels

Tags: centos, centos7, kernel

As you can see below, there might be (as far as I understand) two kernel versions being installed. Also I get

> "**grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template**"

the reinstall ends successfully but I need to understand what should I do ?

iI want only the latest version of the kernel,

ps- when i run:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
**CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)**
```

and Here is the output from "yum reinstall kernel":

```
**Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-957.1.3.el7 will be installed
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-957.5.1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Dependencies Resolved
========================================================================================================================
 Package                 Arch                    Version                                 Repository                Size
========================================================================================================================
Reinstalling:
 kernel                  x86_64                  3.10.0-957.1.3.el7                      updates                   48 M
 kernel                  x86_64                  3.10.0-957.5.1.el7                      updates                   48 M
Not available:
 kernel                  x86_64                  3.10.0-693.21.1.el7                     -                        0.0
 kernel                  x86_64                  3.10.0-862.14.4.el7                     -                        0.0
 kernel                  x86_64                  3.10.0-862.11.6.el7                     -                        0.0
Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Reinstall      2 Packages
Not available  3 Packages
Total download size: 96 M
Installed size: 126 M
Downloading packages:
(1/2): kernel-3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                      |  48 MB  00:00:03
(2/2): kernel-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                                      |  48 MB  00:00:03
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                    28 MB/s |  96 MB  00:00:03
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : kernel-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64                                                                     1/2
grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template
  Installing : kernel-3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64                                                                     2/2
grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template
  Verifying  : kernel-3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64                                                                     1/2
  Verifying  : kernel-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64                                                                     2/2
Installed:
  kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-957.1.3.el7                         kernel.x86_64 0:3.10.0-957.5.1.el7
Complete!
```

Comment: What is the command you ran? On what hardware is this running?

Comment: > sudo yum -y reinstall kernel